# Fast swapping framebuffers OpenGL

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I recently read that simply switching the render targets of a framebuffer object is much faster than switching framebuffer object.

As extreme as it sounds, does this this mean I should only ever use one framebuffer object and only switchout it's targets?

EDIT: I changed 'swapping' to 'switching' to avoid confusion. By switching I mean binding a new framebuffer in place of the old one. Not to be confused with the SwapBuffers() call used to swap the front- and backbuffers.

Comment: Where did you read that? Swapping the framebuffer should take no time at all, unless you have a bug in your driver

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html last paragraph of the overview section.

Comment: A framebuffer is something different than a framebuffer object. The article talks about FBOs.

Comment: I was under the impression that they both mean the same thing. OpenGL officially calls them framebuffer objects, and I couldn't find anything in the specs about a 'framebuffer'.

Comment: In the beginning of the article the differences are explained.

Comment: Although I can't see the difference, I guess I'm using FBOs. So back to my original question, should I only ever use one FBO and only switch its targets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: this answer is probably wrong. Read the comments below.

It's faster to switch framebuffer-attachable textures than switching between framebuffers (FBOs). More here http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html

There are limits to how many attachments a FBO can have though.

Comment: Ah, so you been switching between textures that are already attached to that framebuffer?

Comment: @Hannesh Yes,that's essentially what the article recommends. Haven't done extensive testing though.

Comment: It's very interesting how much directly conflicting information there is on the internet. Just another [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432773/opengl-using-only-one-framebuffer-and-switching-target-textures?rq=1) describes the complete opposite to be true.

Comment: This seems unproven. the article linked provides no timing examples and no explanation of why it might be so. Having effectively written an OpenGL driver I can tell you that switching between framebuffers should be faster than switching attachments. The reason is a framebuffer is only `complete` if a whole set of criteria are true. Everytime you change an attachment all of those criteria need to be checked. On the other hand a framebuffer that has already been checked doesn't need to be checked again. QED switching framebuffers should be faster.

Comment: What gman said. From Valve's OpenGL talks and John McDonald/Cass Everitt talks (can't remember if both mentioned it or just one), FBO validation can take a "long" time, whereas switching already prevalidated FBOs is less expensive.