# Is there any way to use results of a previous rendering inside a fragment shader?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm using the fragment shader to render to a texture. I would like the rendering of the previous iteration of the shader to be used by the next one. How is that possible?

Comment: Sample here http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-image-processing-continued/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To re-use the texture in the fragment shader:

either

- unbind the current framebuffer object (bind the `null` framebuffer object or bind another framebuffer object) to which the texture is attached,

or

- detach the texture from the framebuffer object (and attach `null`, attach another texture with `framebufferTexture2D` or attach a renderbuffer instead).

and then bind the texture as a normal texture to be used in the fragment shader (via  `sampler2D` and `texture2D` in the shader code).

To re-use the texture in the vertex shader, it is roughly the same, except that this feature (vertex textures) is non-standard (and has some limitations). Check [MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ#Why_don.27t_textures_work_in_my_vertex_shader_on_browser.2Fmachine.2Fos_XXX.3F) for support.

If you have an iterative algorithm that requires multiple rendering passes, one typical approach is to switch between two textures 1 and 2: during odd rendering passes, 1 is attached to the current framebuffer object and 2 is bound as a normal texture and during even rendering passes, it's the opposite. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435997/3146587) on whether texture attachments should be changed in a single framebuffer object or whole framebuffer objects should instead be swapped.

Comment: How do you detach it from the framebuffer? Could you include some code example for that first paragraph?

Comment: framebuffers should be swapped. Changing an attachment should be a much more expensive operation. For a framebuffer to be *complete* a whole bunch of things have to be true. Every time you attach/detach all of those things need to be checked. Conversely if the framebuffer is already *complete* nothing needs to be checked so swapping framebuffers can be instant whereas swapping attachments is likely slow. On the other hand, the likelihood that either method is going to be a bottleneck is pretty low.

Comment: You detach an attachment by attaching 'null' to that attachment point. `gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);` attaches `texture` to `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Change `texture` to `null` to bind `null` to `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` which is effectively detaches `texture`.